# Elementary proof that $Gl_n(\mathbb R)$ and $Gl_m(R)$ are homeomorphic iff $n=m$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

> Prove that $Gl_n(\mathbb R)$ and $Gl_m(R)$ are homeomorphic iff $n=m$

Since $Gl_n(\mathbb R)$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, this boils down to proving that two open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ are homeomorphic iff $n=m$.

This can be done via homology, of which I know absolutely nothing.

Do you know a proof that doesn't cover things an undergraduate isn't supposed to know ?

**EDIT**: I'll close the question, since it's a duplicate of [Elementary proof that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/elementary-proof-that-mathbbrn-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrm)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain.

Comment: You are basically asking for a proof that the dimension of a manifold is a topological invariant. There are proofs that do not use homology, and they are not short, but they may be accessible to a very energetic undergraduate. See for example the book by Hurewicz and Wallman, "Dimension Theory".

Comment: related (essentially duplicate of?): [Elementary proof that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/24873/)

Comment: I'd say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathrm{GL}_m(\mathbb{R})$, then (using that these are $n^2$-dimensional resp. $m^2$-dimensional manifolds) it follows that there is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m^2}$. It is well-known that this implies $n=m$ and there a lot of proofs for this, also without homology. See [SE/24873](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/elementary-proof-that-mathbbrn-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrm?rq=1) and [arXiv:1310.8090](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8090).