# Isomorphism between general linear groups

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $GL_{n}(\mathbb{F})$ be the set of all $n \times n$ invertible matrices over a field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic $0$.

Whether $GL_{r}(\mathbb{F})$ is isomorphic to $GL_{s}(\mathbb{F})$ for $r \neq s$? I think that $GL_{r}(\mathbb{F}) \not\cong GL_{s}(\mathbb{F})$ for $r \neq s$, but I don't know how to prove it. I need to a strict proof.

Comment: Related on MO (this is a different question): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106838/isomorphic-general-linear-groups-implies-isomorphic-fields

Comment: @ Watson Thank you very much.

Comment: $GL_1(F) = F^{\times}$ is abelian, while $GL_2(F)$ is not.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908104/give-a-simple-proof-gl-1-mathbbf-not-cong-gl-2-mathbbf

Comment: @ Watson https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686695/is-there-a-simple-way-of-proving-that-textgl-nr-not-cong-textgl-mr  For $m \neq n$, $m,n \geq 2$, $\text{GL}_{m}(\mathbb{F})$ and $\text{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{F})$ are not elementarily equivalent, how we get $\text{GL}_{m}(\mathbb{F}) \not\cong \text{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{F})$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44671/discussion-between-bing-and-watson).