# Can this be a way to prove that $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}^3$ are not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

The normal way I use to prove that $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$ are not homeomorphic is by removing a point and then using path connectedness.
But this method doesn't seem to work for $\Bbb{R}^m$ and $\Bbb{R}^n$ and it ends up that its better if you use fundamental groups.

But what if I remove a line instead of a point from both the topological spaces. Does the argument still fail or will it lead to a proof?

Comment: it fails. The intuition about it is that in dimension higher than $1$ you can always go around a hole in a path connected way. This is why you need shrink continuously your path around the hole and this leads to compare simple connectedness (i.e fundamental groups and homotopy)

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/elementary-proof-that-mathbbrn-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrm?rq=1)

Comment: If you want to use only connectivity argument, then you might be fail because proving connectivity of $\mathbb{R}^3 - f(\mathbb{R})$ is not as easy as connectivity of $\mathbb{R}^2-pt$.

Comment: I want to see for a line which might be a little wacky @cjackal

Comment: Your dot over the "i" in homeomorphic was upside-down and I corrected it.  Or to be a bit more precise, I actually changed $\Bbb{R^m}$ and $\Bbb{R^n}$ to $\Bbb{R}^m$ and $\Bbb{R}^n$, which is correct usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, yes, but it is quite hard to prove that removing a subspace homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}$ (your "line") cannot disconnect $\mathbb{R}^3$. The [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) states that any continuous embedding of a circle in the plane disconnects it and that implies that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are not homeomorphic via an argument along the lines of the one you have in mind. Brouwer's theorem on the [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) generalises this and implies that $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are homeomorphic iff $m = n$. Both the Jordan curve theorem and invariance of domain are usually proved using homology theory.

Answer (score 8):

If $m<n$, then we can make $\mathbb{R}^m$ disconnected by deleting an $(m-1)$-dimensional subset; more snappily, a *codimension 1* subset. Now, in order to show that $\mathbb{R}^n\not\cong\mathbb{R}^m$, it will suffice to show that, if we delete the homeomorphic image of $\mathbb{R}^{m-1}$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$, the latter remains connected.

This is where things get tricky. For $m=1$ this is easy, since the homeomorphic image of a point is . . . well, a point. :P But the possible homeomorphic images of even a line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are suddenly extremely complicated! I suspect that patching this argument will require using fundamental groups.

---

EDIT: In the comments, the OP writes: "I  want to see for a line which might be a little wacky." Well, first of all, the point is not that there *are* (homeomorphic images of) lines (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) which are wacky, but rather that it would take proof to show there aren't any. As evidence that you should not take this for granted:

- The Jordan curve theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) is hard.
- This **isn't** a line, but it's pretty darn cool, and it should shake your intuitions about lines:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc.
- Not a homeomorphic image, but space-filling curves (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) should cause some worry. In general, fractals probably ought to give one pause.
- Generally, I think algebraic and low-dimensional topology and algebraic geometry will have a lot to say about how weird codimension-one subspaces can be!

---

FURTHER EDIT: On the other hand, this doesn't rule out the possibility of arguments avoiding algebraic topology. For a really neat example, check out http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1467v2.pdf, which uses **set theory** of all things to show $\mathbb{R}^2\not\cong\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n>2$. As far as I can tell, however, their method does not generalize beyond 2.

And see also [Elementary proof that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/elementary-proof-that-mathbbrn-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrm?lq=1).

Comment: You can instead of looking at  connectedness, for $R^2$ vs $R^3$, remove a point and look at fundamental groups. But for higher dimensions, the fundamental group won't help much. What might help is something like Alexander Duality: the $n-1$th homology of $R^n - \{pt\}$ will be $\mathbb Z$, but that won't be true for the $n-1$th homology of $R^m - \{ pt \}$, for $m > n$.

Comment: @JohnHughes $R^n-{pt}$ explicitly deformation retracts to $S^{n-1}$. Alexander duality is way over kill.

Comment: @JohnHughes I want to use normal general topology for the proof which doesn't use either homology or algebraic topology

Comment: @PVAL: completely right. As for "I want to use general topology," I share your desire...but algebraic topology was invented in part precisely to address questions like these. :)

Comment: By the way, the arxiv paper mentioned is so interesting, as the authors said :) I haven't seen similar idea before.

Comment: If you want to use general topology, you could just develop dimension theory, which is morally what we're doing in the algebraic setting anyway: building a notion of dimension.

Comment: See the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky and counterintuitive fact is that there is a surjective continuous map $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$(called space-filling curve).

So, by producting with $id:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, you have a surjective continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which maps $\mathbb{R}\times \left\{0\right\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \left\{0\right\}$.

So, in this case, connectedness argument fails.

(Because there is no homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2 $and $\mathbb{R}^3$, such argument does not cause contradiction, but at least this shows that using connectedness is not a smartest way to show the two space are not homeomorphic)

Comment: To be fair, since that map isn't injective, this doesn't show the argument fails, it just shows it won't be easy . . .