# Open subsets of euclidean space are not homeomorphic unless they belong to the same space

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be homeomorphic open subsets, then $m=n$.

How can I show this?
I think the subsets $U$ and $V$ are supposed to be non-empty. If I assume that $U$ and $V$ are non-epmty, I started by assuming that $m \neq n$. Without loss of generality, I assumed $m <n$ and now I am supposed to obtain a contradiction from here.

Any hint?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Homotopy groups?

Comment: @N.S I am, but I would prefer a simpler explanation

Comment: If I remember right this is why the homotopy groups were invented. The problem is very easy to solve when $m=1$ or $m=2$ but, as far as I know, very hard to solve without Algebraic topology otherwise

Comment: Here is a similar question which has a general topology solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/elementary-proof-that-mathbbrn-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrm

Comment: This is not a trivial theorem but there are lots of different proofs for this theorem.

Comment: modern treatment https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.8090.pdf

Comment: @N.S. Brouwer (who first showed this) did it without algebraic topology. My general topology course also treated this without. It’s hard but not insurmountable.

Comment: This is known as [the invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) and it is a major theorem, far from trivial. And AFAIK we can only solve it using algebraic topology.