# proving that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm struggling for proving that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are not homeomorphic for $n \ge3.$ My approach is similar to proof of the state below.

> $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are not homeomorphic for n$\ge$2.

More specifically, suppose to the contrary that there is homeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ . Since $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\mathbb{S}^{1}$ is **NOT** connected and it has separation $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid \left|x \right|<1\}$ and $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid \left| x \right| >1\}.$ I know intuitively that $\mathbb{R}^{n}-h \left( \mathbb{S}^{1}\right)$ is connected, but I cannot prove mathematically.

Comment: Do you know fundamental group?

Comment: You can show that $\mathbb R^n\setminus \{x\}$ is simply connected for $n>2,$ and not for $n=2.$

Comment: @ArcticChar I know fundamental group.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I can use the fact that If a space is star convex, in other words, there is a point that all the other points can be connected by **straight line segment**, then it is simply connected. But If I remove {**0**} at $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, It is not star convex and therefore I must use different method. can you give me approach for this?

Comment: I'll stick by the approach I sketched [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24875/4280): use dimension theory.

Comment: I recommend also reading some closely related posts on this topic, particularly this one and it's various answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/elementary-proof-that-mathbbrn-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrm?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach works smoother if you flip the direction around.

Suppose you have a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^2$ and consider a *fixed* closed nonintersecting curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb R^n$ that you can describe nicely. If you choose a nice straightforward circle, it will be easy to show that $\mathbb R^n\setminus\gamma$ is path-connected. On the other hand, $f(\gamma)$ is a Jordan curve in $\mathbb R^2$, so $\mathbb R^2\setminus f(\gamma)$ is *not* connected, a contradiction. (This assumes you can appeal to the Jordan curve theorem without proving it yourself).

Comment: Oh! switching role of domain and range gives more convenient way of proof. I was struggling that image of circle is not planar curve in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but starting with planar curve in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and using the fact that continuous image of loop is also loop helps me to complete my proof.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with algebraic topology, I will give you a very simple argument for this. Let $1\le m<n$ and suppose there was a homeomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Removing any $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and the corresponding point $f(x)$ from their respective spaces, we have (still homeomorphic) punctured euclidean spaces. The first is homotopy equivalent to $S^{m-1}$, and the second to $S^{n-1}$. This gives us their homologies, $H_*(\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{ x\}) \cong H_*(S^{m-1})$ and $H_*(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{ f(x)\})\cong H_*(S^{n-1})$.

We know that $n\ge2$, so $H_k(S^{n-1}) = 0$ if $k\neq 0, n-1$ and $H_0(S^{n-1})\cong \mathbb{Z} \cong H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$. The same holds for $S^{m-1}$ (with $n$ replaced by $m$) if $m\ge2$, but if $m=1$, then $H_0(S^{m-1})\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}, H_k(S^{n-1})=0$ for $k\ge1$. Since the punctured spaces are homeomorphic to one another and homotopy equivalent to those spheres, the spheres are then homotopy equivalent to one another. This means that they have isomorphic homologies, but then $\mathbb{Z} \cong H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \cong H_{n-1}(S^{m-1}) = 0$, since $m\neq n$. This is an absurdity, and therefore the punctured spaces cannot be homeomorphic. Since the homeomorphism between them was obtained from a homeomorphism between the original euclidean spaces, such a homeomorphism cannot exist.

Comment: Ah.. I cannot use **homology**.

Comment: Can you use homotopy? I can modify that to work for homotopy groups. The answer is probably going to be no, though.

Comment: I can use fundamental group and homotopy itself, but I did not learned about homotopy **group**. I have few tools of algebraic topology.

Comment: I see. Then you can discard my ideas.

Comment: The original post is only about the case $m=2$, i.e. about the proof that $\mathbb R^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ for $n \ge 3$. So one needs only the concept of "fundamental group", otherwise known as "first homotopy group".

Comment: @LeeMosher oh right! I forgot that completely. Good point.