# Possible mistake in a Theorem: just a worksheet!

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I am supposed to prove the following result in my worksheet:

**Exercise.** Show that any two finite-dimensional normed spaces are homeomorphic. In particular, show that every normed space (over $\Bbb {K}$) of dimension $n$ is isomorph to $\Bbb K^n.$

**My concern.** One should know that, for example, $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$ are not homeomorphic ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24873/elementary-proof-that-mathbbrn-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrm), for $m \neq n$). Since $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$ are normed spaces  (there are several known norms defined on such spaces) with finite dimension ($n$ and $m$, respectively) this contradicts the statement (?).

I believe that for finite-dimensional normed spaces with the **same** dimension the result is valid and it isn't hard to prove. But like this, I can't see how this is true.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Indeed the statement isn't correct. The spaces must have the same dimension to be homeomorphic.

Comment: The second half of the exercise makes it sound like the original intent was indeed to show that any two finite-dimensional spaces of the same dimension $n$ are homeomorphic (and thus in particular are homeomorphic to $k^n$ under the usual norm).

Comment: Yup... Probably just a typo! Thanks for the feedback.